# How to use the Linear Gauge Series plugin by Highcharts?

Tags: angular, highcharts, gauge

I want to create the linear gauge series example given by Highcharts. I have attached the link for the demo : https://www.highcharts.com/samples/highcharts/studies/linear-gauge-series
I want to display the same in an angular application. How to convert this code so that it runs in angular?

(PS: I cannot use a bullet chart because I need the triangle marker which is offered in linear gauge)

Comment: what did you try ? are you stuck somewhere ?

Answer (score 0):

You might do this in the Angular, very similar to what you send in JS.
I moved this wrap into a separate file which is fired at the beginning.
The only thing which might cause trouble is the TS. But you can follow the [wrapper documentation](https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts-angular) where you might find the solution for that.

**Demo:** https://stackblitz.com/edit/highcharts-angular-custom-plugin-o6ered

Comment: This solves the problem! Thanks for the solution!!